# How can I convert this old dplyr syntax?

Tags: r, dplyr, across

I am new to dplyr and I'm having difficulties in (i) understanding its syntax and (ii) transforming its old version code into a code I can use in its newest version (dplyr 1.0.2). In particular, I'm confused about the two following lines of code :

```
mutate_each(funs(replace(.,.=="NOT ANSWERED",NA))) %>%     
mutate_each(funs(ordered(.,c("NOT AT ALL","ONCE A WEEK", "2-4 TIMES PER WEEK/HALF THE TIME", "5 OR MORE TIMES PER WEEK/ALMOST ALWAYS"))))
```

I think that the first line of code is supposed to replace all the "NOT ANSWERED" with NA.

Do you think that the following transformation is appropariate?

```
mutate(across(everything(),~replace(., .== "NOT ANSWERED", NA)))
```

However, I don't understand what the second line of code is about. I believe that it's about creating some sort of ordered variable with "NOT AT ALL", "ONCE A WEEK", "2-4 TIMES PER WEEK/HALF THE TIME" and "5 OR MORE TIMES PER WEEK/ALMOST ALWAYS" as levels.

Do you have any suggestion on what this line does and on how to convert it into the new syntax with mutate(across())?

**Some context**

I'm trying to follow a tutorial on how to use the Bootnet R package. The following text comes from the [first part](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Sacha_Epskamp/publication/308076646_Supplementary/links/57d91dc508ae5f03b499e015/Supplementary.pdf) of the tutorial

> To download the dataset, go to:
> https://datashare.nida.nih.gov/study/nida-ctn-0015 and click on
> “CTN-0015 Data Files”. The relevant data file is called “qs.csv”,
> which can be loaded into R by using the default read.csv function:
>
> FullData <- read.csv("qs.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
>
> This loads the data in long format, which contains a column with
> subject id’s, a column with the names of the administered items, and a
> third column containing the item responses. For network analysis, we
> need the data to be in wide format. Furthermore, we need to assign
> that the response "NOT ANSWERED" indicates a missing response and
> other responses are ordinal. Finally, we need to extract relevant
> dataset at baseline measure for the PTSD symptom frequency scores. To
> do this, we can utilize the dplyr and tidyr R packages as follows:
>
> ```
> # Load packages: 
> library("dplyr") 
> library("tidyr") 
>
> # Frequency at baseline: 
> Data <- FullData %>% 
>         filter(EPOCH == "BASELINE",grepl("^PSSR\\d+A$",QSTESTCD)) %>% 
>         select(USUBJID,QSTEST,QSORRES) %>% 
>         spread(QSTEST, QSORRES) %>% 
>         select(-USUBJID) %
>         mutate_each(funs(replace(.,.=="NOT ANSWERED",NA))) %>% 
>         mutate_each(funs(ordered(.,c("NOT AT ALL","ONCE A WEEK", "2-4 TIMES PER WEEK/HALF THE TIME", "5 OR MORE TIMES PER WEEK/ALMOST ALWAYS"))))
>
> names(Data) <- seq_len(ncol(Data))
> ```

The tutorial keeps going in its [second part](https://scholarlypublications.universiteitleiden.nl/access/item%3A2970252/view).

Comment: "I believe that it's about creating some sort of ordered variable" - yes. An ordered factor to be precise

Comment: "how to convert it into the new syntax with mutate(across())"... I think you have probably managed well with the first call to across. What have you tried for this second line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ordered` is used to create an ordered factor in the order it is presented. Since both the calls are applied to same columns you can combine them into one function. Try :

```
library(dplyr)

vals <- c("NOT AT ALL","ONCE A WEEK", "2-4 TIMES PER WEEK/HALF THE TIME", "5 OR MORE TIMES PER WEEK/ALMOST ALWAYS")

Data <- FullData %>%
          #....
          #....
          #....
          mutate(across(.fns = ~ordered(replace(., .== "NOT ANSWERED", NA), vals)))
```